# Can't find the right Ubuntu Server ISO for VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtual-machine, iso-image

I have been trying all morning to find the right Ubuntu Server (12.04) ISO to use for installing an Ubuntu guest OS on my VBox VM.

Here are the relevant stats:

- Host Machine: AMD 64-bit
- Host OS: Ubuntu Desktop 11.04
- VM OS: Linux
- VM OS Version: Ubuntu
- ISO downloaded and attempted: `ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso`

When I try to start the VM I get a main menu, the first option reads *Install Ubuntu*. When I select that, I get an error message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

**Edit**: That message makes me think that I have a *32-bit* machine but am trying to run a 64-bit ISO. I am **confident** that this is 64-bit, however, as `uname -m` produces `x86-64` in the terminal...and executing `lscpu` produces:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1200.000
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
```

Here's the kicker: I downloaded the ISO on a Windows machine, because my Ubuntu machine (the one running Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 and hosting the VM-to-be) has crummy network connection. So I downloaded to a Windows client, put the ISO on a flash drive, copied it over to my Ubuntu machine, and saved it locally. I'm wondering if the download page saw that I was trying to download from a Windows client and swapped out the x86-64 version for i686? Otherwise I downloaded the wrong ISO.

Can someone please tell me what the right ISO is? I thought for sure the AMD 64-bit version would be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ISO is probably the correct one. What you need to do is make sure you are setting up a 64bit Virtual Machine. From the [VBox website](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html) (emphasis mine):

### 64-bit guests

> VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit
>   host operating systems, provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see the section called “[Hardware vs. software virtualization](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt)”).
> 2. You **must enable hardware virtualization** for the particular VM for which you want 64-bit support; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> 3. If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, **you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM**. Since supporting 64 bits on 32-bit hosts incurs additional overhead, VirtualBox only enables this support upon explicit request.
>
>    On 64-bit hosts (which typically come with hardware virtualization support), 64-bit guest operating systems are always supported
>      regardless of settings, so you can simply install a 64-bit operating
>      system in the guest.
>
> Warning
>
> On any host, you should enable the I/O APIC for virtual machines that
>   you intend to use in 64-bit mode. This is especially true for 64-bit
>   Windows VMs. See the section called “"[Advanced" tab](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-general-advanced)”. In addition, for
>   64-bit Windows guests, you should make sure that the VM uses the Intel
>   networking device, since there is no 64-bit driver support for the AMD
>   PCNet card; see the section called “Virtual networking hardware”.
>
> **If you use the "Create VM" wizard of the VirtualBox graphical user
>   interface (see the section called “Creating your first virtual
>   machine”), VirtualBox will automatically use the correct settings for
>   each selected 64-bit operating system type.**

So, just try creating a new Virtual Machine and select Ubuntu 64 as the OS. All the settings should be correctly configured by VirtualBox and you should be able to install with no problems.

Comment: Thanks @terdon (+1) - please see my comment under p0rkjello's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: @zharvey No, you do not have an AMD processor. You _are_, however, on an x86_64 architecture. Apple and AMD were the first to come out with a 64bit system for personal computers. So, in the non mac world, amd64 was adopted for all 64bit architectures. x86_64 was later adopted to describe intel 64bit CPUs as well. The two names are essentially synonymous today.

Comment: I don't get the third point _"If you want to use 64-bit guest support on a 32-bit host operating system, you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM"_. `you must also select a 64-bit operating system for the particular VM` what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta that just means that you should install a 64bit operating system on your virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can download from one of the mirrors directly. And yes  [ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso](http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases/12.04/) is the correct 64bit version.

Perhaps you are running a 32bit base OS. Run uname -a to check the kernel version.
Below is an example of a 64bit output.

```
p0rkjello@de01u0001:~$ uname -a
Linux de01u0001 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The output from an AMD system I own

```
p0rkjello@de01u0001:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                6
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-5
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
```

Comment: Thanks @p0rkjello (+1) - I am just noticing the `Vendor ID: GenuineIntel` in the `lscpu` output. Does that mean I'm not AMD like I thought? Thanks again!

Comment: Correct. The output of Vendor ID would state AMD Or Intel.