# Can't I install a 64 bit OS as a guest OS,when the host OS is 32 bit

Tags: windows, virtualbox, 64-bit

I read it somewhere *"If you are running virtual box on a 32 bit OS, you cannot install a 64 bit OS as a guest OS (in virtual box)."* Is it true ?

If so, I want to know the reason ?

*Note: I am using windows 7-32 bit, with intel dual core processor.*

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/464370/151431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a x64 guest in a x86 host if and only if:

1. your CPU supports 64bit
2. your CPU/BIOS support Intel's virtualization extensions (VT-x) and they are enabled.

see more info here, in the section "Software based virtualization":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization

Make sure your BIOS is configured to enable the virtualization extensions, and it should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question which is slightly on the complex side.

1. 64bit operating systems require CPUs which can handle longer and more accurate numbers, which 32 bit OS can't.
2. You can however run 32bit on 64bit machines...you just lose one of the major pros for 64bit. The following link is quite educational if you are willing to read it all the way through.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm

Comment: since the op's CPU is 64bit, and their OS is 32bit, they can run a 64bit guest. this is confirmed by the articles in your answer and my own.

Comment: Missed that comment.