# Dependency problems due to conflicts when installing Ubuntu Mini

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Mini (obtained at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso) to a VirtualBox VM, and running into a weird problem:

[image]

There seem to be more than a hundred packages all with the same kind of conflict, between package_name and package_name:i386. How should I resolve this?

More details:

I'm trying to install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 13.04 from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD onto my 64-bit Windows 7. I've given the guest OS "Version" as "Ubuntu (64 bit)" in VirtualBox. In the choose-predefined-collection stage I chose only "Basic Ubuntu server" and "Manual package selection" since I want only a basic commandline, no GUI.

Comment: Are you installing a 32bit or 64bit version? Have you set up a 32bit or 64bit VM?

Comment: I'm installing the 64 bit version of 13.04 from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD, and have given the guest OS as "Ubuntu 64" in VirtualBox. Is there a setting elsewhere to set it as a 64 bit VM?

Comment: @terdon I've answered the 32bit-64bit question in the previous comment, but for now I disabled "Manual package selection" in the installer and so avoided this problem, but I'm not sure if it'll come up again if I try to use apt-get after installation.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/464370/151431).