# Having problems install win7 by using virtualbox in ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

After installing ubuntu 12.10 on my notebook, I just tried to install Windows 7 64 bit with service pack by using virtualbox.

By the time I run virtualbox ,the system said fail to boot.

I'm pretty sure that the right iso file that just downloaded have been chosen and can't find anything that could cause this problem.

Can anyone help me solve it ?

Comment: Did you create a 64bit virtual machine? See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/464370/151431).